# User Redirection based on Roles | Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to redirect user to other view based on their roles.

for admin i want to redirect it to /home view and for normal user redirect it to emDashboard view. can anyone help me with this?

Thank you guys.

this is my Login Controller

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except([
        'logout',
    ]);
}

public function login()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}

public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email'     =>  'required|string|email',
        'password'  =>  'required|string',
    ]);

    $email      = $request->email;
    $password   = $request->password;

    $dt         = Carbon::now();
    $todayDate  = $dt->toDayDateTimeString();

    $activityLog = [

        'name'          => $email,
        'email'         => $email,
        'description'   => 'has log in',
        'date_time'     => $todayDate,
    ];
        if (Auth::attempt(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password,'status'=>'Active'])) {
            DB::table('activity_logs')->insert($activityLog);
            Toastr::success('Login successfully :)','Success');
            return redirect()->intended('home');
        }elseif (Auth::attempt(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password,'status'=> null])) {
            DB::table('activity_logs')->insert($activityLog);
            Toastr::success('Login successfully :)','Success');
            return redirect()->intended('home');
        }else{
            Toastr::error('fail, Wrong Username or Password','Error');
            return redirect('login');
        }
}
```

Route for Login and Home Dashboard

```
Route::controller(LoginController::class)->group(function (){
Route::get('/login', 'login')->name('login');
Route::post('/login', 'Authenticate');
Route::get('/logout', 'logout')->name('logout');


Route::controller(HomeController::class)->group(function () {
Route::get('/home', 'index')->name('home');
Route::get('em/dashboard', 'emDashboard')->name('em/dashboard');
```

this is the users Model

```
protected $table = 'users';
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'rec_id',
    'email',
    'join_date',
    'phone_number',
    'status',
    'role_name',
    'avatar',
    'password',
];
```

Comment: You will have to customize this file : https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php to your needs and change $redirectTo inside LoginController accordingly

Comment: This helped me with a similar situation https://medium.com/fabcoding/laravel-redirect-users-according-to-roles-and-protect-routes-bde324fe1823\

Comment: ``return redirect()->intended('home');`` before calling this line you have to check the role of the authenticated user and then redirect to the specific view based on the user role !!

Comment: @Lk77 only if you're using the default login controller provided by Laravel.

Comment: Also, optimise the authentication validation if statements.

Comment: @dz0nika your comment was helpful also. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a if check before `return redirect()->intended('home');` in your authenticate method...  something like this

```
if(Auth()->user()->role_name == "admin"){
    return redirect()->intended('home');
    
} else {
    return redirect()->intended('em/dashboard');
}
```